# Why is my JavaScript scroll up/down event not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, scroll

I'm trying to make a similar effect like on [this website](http://buckymaler.com/global/) were when you scroll down the side navigation element gets a class of `active`, and to previous that class is removed. The problem in my code is that when i scroll down it scrolls only to the next element and then doesnt want to move from there...

Here is my **snippet**:

```js
(function() {

  // scroll container elements
  var parent_el = document.getElementById('container');
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    var count = 0;

    if (event.deltaY > 0) {

      if (el.item(count).classList.contains('current')) {
        el.item(count).classList.remove('current');
      }
      count++;
      el.item(count).classList.add('current');
    } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {

    }

  });

}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.line-container {
  width: 100px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}
.current {
  width: 45px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}
.long {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-container" id="container">
  <div class="line current"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<div class="long"></div>
```

Comment: There's too much code in your question. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to move the variable, "count", out of the addEventListener callback function, because the function always resets count to be zero.
2. The wheel event will be triggered multi-times, so you have to only handle this event once. The most simple way to skip these annoy events is to wait for one second.

   `var count = 0, wait = 300, animationStartTime = 0;
   window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
   var now = (new Date()).getTime();
   if (now - animationStartTime < wait) {
       // Wait for the animation and skip wheel event util the animation is completed.
       return;
   }
   if (event.deltaY > 50) {
     animationStartTime = (new Date()).getTime(); 
     ...
   }`

Comment: but if i scroll too fast, it happens that in one moment none of the elements will have the class of "current" and then my whole addEventListener function doesnt work...

Comment: Adjust the value of wait, also increase the value of the vertical scroll amount. I have changed my example : wait = 300, event.deltaY > 50, it is good for me.

Comment: But still if you scroll to fast, when you reach the end none of the elements will have class of current and then function is useless, please check out my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6L0ytxka/1/

Comment: When you scroll down at the end of element, do you want the current element move to the first element?  See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6L0ytxka/3/ you need to reset the count when the count equals to the size of elements.

Comment: Could you please do the same, when you scroll up, so when you reach the first element again and scroll up it would go to the last element

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked isn't actually a really long page, it's only the size of the window. Notice there is no browser vertical scroll bar.

What it does instead is bind custom functionality to the `wheel` event:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {

        // switch to next element

    } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {

        // switch to previous element

    }
});
```

This way, it doesn't matter how "long" your page is. No need for that `<br><br><br><br>...` eyesore.

Comment: i have edited the post now, your answer is really good, but now how do i make it that on event.deltaY > 0 it scrolls down, mine wants to scroll only once, and then doesnt continue, because the deltaY is still > 0, so it probably thinks it should stop there, is there a way to reset the deltaY to 0?

Comment: The `deltaY` field is how much the y-position changed in that one scroll event. If you continue to scroll down, the event will fire multiple times, and each event will have a `deltaY` that is > 0.